# RAML structure for Arrays

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, raml, raml-1.0

My JSON input is as below

```json
{
  "test" : ["t1259", "t2895"]
}
```

I want to generate RAML data type for the above as below but it is failing with the validation, please let me know whether the below RAML data type is the correct representation for the above JSON.

```yaml
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
    
type: object
properties:
  test:
    type: array
    items:
      properties:
        type: string
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you want an array of strings:

```
type: string[]
```

Comment: Yes I want array of strings

Answer (score 0):

What you have defined is an Array of Objects, where each object has a field "type" of type "string". The problem is in the following part.

```yaml
items:
  properties: # This is the problem. You have defined "properties" in each item. RAML thinks that it is an object with property "type"
  type: string
```

So your RAML will accept this array: `[{"type": "stringvalue"}]`
You have to remove the `properties` keyword under `items`. Or you can use the shorthand version that Aled mentioned in his answer (which is more readable too, but I am mentioning this as sometimes you may need to define complex objects in which case you will have to use the below one).

```yaml
#%RAML 1.0 DataType

type: object
properties:
  test:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string # This means that type of each item is string
```

Answer (score 0):

#%RAML 1.0

title: ValidatorApps

types:

InputType: !include example/json_schema.json

/validate:

description: "This call will validate the input payload"

post:

```
body:

  application/json:

    type: InputType

    example: !include example/input_file.json

responses:

  200:

    body:

      application/json:

        example:

          {"Success" : "Successfully validated"}
```

### Please find the above raml.

Please find the

- json_schema.json

file code

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "test"
  ]
}
```

---

Please find the

- input json file

  {
  "test" : ["t1259", "t2895"]
  }